# Why does my laptop's power brick "tick" when connected to A/C while not also connected to the computer

Tags: laptop, power-supply

I recently got a new [14" 2013 Razer Blade](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-systems/razer-blade/), and found that the power brick has a weird behavior.

When I plug the brick into the wall, after a few seconds, it will start to produce a "tick, tick" noise on a very consistent interval. When I plug the other end into the computer the sound will cease. But when I unplug my computer the sound will return after a few seconds.

What causes this sound? Is there potentially a problem with my adapter?

Comment: This is not normal.  The sound could be caused by any number of standard electronic parts, with that said, I would contact the OEM and request a replacement.

Comment: For the record, the laptop is the 14" 2013 Razer Blade. Has anyone else experienced the same behavior?

Comment: UPDATE: I contacted the manufacturer, and the support agent claimed this was not abnormal (though he didn't say it was actually normal) and claimed there was nothing wrong. However he seemed very dismissive, and could not explain why it was making the noise. I intend to contact them again and talk to another agent.

Comment: Don't worry it won't create major problem to your adaptor as well as laptop.

Answer (score 4):

The sound is often caused by electricity being repeatedly discharged because there is a short circuit inside the power adapter, or it's being overloaded, or the power being fed to it from the wall is really dirty.

To test for dirty power from the source, you may want to test it in another socket in the house, and then in a completely different building to see if it still does it.

My goal would be to replace it ASAP.  [Contact Razer's RMA department](http://www.razersupport.com/) and tell them about it. They may give you a more precise answer, or at least tell you if it's considered normal or not (not, IME), and/or help you return it.

Comment: I have tried outlets in multiple rooms/buildings - same thing. I will be calling support as soon as I get the chance.

Comment: If this is some sort of short as noted, there could be a fire or other undesired result.  Call sooner rather than later and assure the adapter is not on a combustible surface